# Dividing a Pandas series with the same series shifted one place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series, a time and a value.
I would like to calculate the changes between each value.
Like this: current value / previous value.

When I run this code:

```
print now.head(n=3)
print before.head(n=3)
delta = now.divide(before)
print delta.iloc[1]
print now.iloc[1] / before.iloc[1]
```

I get this result:

```
DateTime
2014-01-08 09:27:00    623.53836
2014-01-08 09:28:00    623.54066
2014-01-08 09:32:00    623.53846
Name: close, dtype: float64
DateTime
2014-01-08 09:26:00    624.01000
2014-01-08 09:27:00    623.53836
2014-01-08 09:28:00    623.54066
Name: close, dtype: float64
1.0
1.00000368863
```

What am I missing since the last two numbers are not the same?

The series now and before are the same series, only shifted one place.

**Update**: The problem was the indexes which pandas matches when dividing. Luckily pandas has the built-in function called .pct_change() that does exactly what I want. Thank you Steven G. for showing me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that when you do `delta = now.divide(before)`it will match indexes. so delta.iloc[1] will be `623.53836 / 623.53836` representing the division on `2014-01-08 09:27:00` index

when you use integer location `now.iloc[1] / before.iloc[1]` it doesn't care about the index so it does `623.54066 / 623.53836`

remember that `.iloc[1]` is the second row and `.iloc[0]` is the first row

Comment: I think his question is why do  "delta.iloc[1]" and "now.iloc[1] / before.iloc[1]" differ

Comment: Both of those returns a bunch of 1.0's.

Comment: The formatting makes no difference. The two last results are still the same: 1.0 vs 1.00000368863

Comment: That would explain it. Now I just have to figure out how to stop it from matching indexes.

Comment: @Nis what are you trying to achieve ? percentage change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125243/discussion-between-steven-g-and-nis).

Answer (score 0):

You could divide by the values:

```
now['delta'] = now.values / before.values
```

This will add a new column to your now dataframe of course.

Alternately, if you want this in its own dataframe you could write:

```
delta = now.copy()
delta['delta'] = now.close.values / before.close.values
delta.drop('close', 1, inplace=True)
```